# Stop all form submit in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My need is to interrupt all form submit of my webpage and need to add a extra input field to it. I need to do it with js/Jquery.

I can do this for single form (using name/ID). But I need to do it for all 100s of form submit in my website. (In my case all forms are submitted using the form element's `submit()` method [not jQuery's `submit()`].)

Is there any way I can do it? Like overriding actual `form.submit()` method?

Comment: Please provide some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my case all forms are submitted using javascript submit() method

In that case, you can wrap that method. Which is important, because when you call the DOM's `HTMLFormElement#submit` method, `submit` event handlers are **not** triggered. (If you use jQuery's `submit` method instead, it does trigger handlers before submitting the form.)

Here's how you wrap that function without using any libraries:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("form"), function(form) {
    var realSubmit = form.submit;
    form.submit = function() {
        // Do your stuff
        // ...
        // Submit the form
        realSubmit.call(form);
    };
});
```

...or as you've tagged your question `jquery`, with jQuery:

```
$("form").each(function() {
    var form = this;
    var realSubmit = form.submit;
    form.submit = function() {
        // Do your stuff
        // ...

        // Submit the form
        realSubmit.call(form);
    };
});
```

You'll need to check that your target browsers allow it. Modern ones do.

Here's a complete example: [**Live Copy**](https://jsbin.com/xohuxa/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This page adds the q field to a form it submits to Google</p>
  <form method="GET" action="http://google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input id="sendDOM" type="button" value="Send with DOM's submit">
    <input id="sendjQuery" type="button" value="Send with jQuery's submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    $("#sendDOM").click(function() {
      $("form")[0].submit();
    });
    $("#sendjQuery").click(function() {
      $("form").submit();
    });

    // Wrap submit on the forms
    $("form").each(function() {
      var form = this;
      var realSubmit = form.submit;
      form.submit = function() {
        // Do your stuff
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        el.type = "hidden";
        el.name = "q";
        el.value = "kittens";
        form.appendChild(el);

        // Submit the form
        realSubmit.call(form);
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The javascript prototype working fine for me.Need to check with different browsers. @T.J Thanks man

Comment: @VishnuprabhuGopalakrishnan: No worries.

Comment: Your answer is the best fit for my problem :) Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You select and find the form in your page using $('form') selector.

it returns all the forms inside your page.

then bind the submit event.

```
var ajaxFormSubmit = function(){  

//write what you need to do

return false;

};


$('form').submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

Comment: The OP said *"In my case all forms are submitted using javascript submit() method"* The above won't work if the forms are being submitted via the DOM's `HTMLFormElement#submit` method, only if the OP is using jQuery's `submit` to submit the form. When you call the DOM's `submit`, event handlers are **not triggered**. (But if you use jQuery's wrapper for it, jQuery does trigger handlers.) That's why I asked the question on the question.

Comment: The OP has now confirmed that it's the DOM's `submit` they're using, so this simply will not work.